# Angular Material md-list flexing

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I want to use Angular Material's md-list for showing elements, using responsive design. And my task is to show these items in 1 column if media device is small and in 3 columns if it's larger than small.
I was thinkink of something like this:

```
<md-list layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <md-list-item flex="33" flex-sm="100" class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="md-list-item-text">
      <h3>{{occasionType.occasionType}}</h3>
      <p>{{occasionType.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone help?

Comment: what is the issue, can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `layout-sm="column"`

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap  layout-sm="column">
<div flex="33" class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="item in items">
<div class="md-list-item-text">
  <h3>{{occasionType.occasionType}}</h3>
  <p>{{occasionType.name}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It works for me.